# CKFinder ConnectorBuilder is raising a generic type definition exception on startup of asp.net mvc web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with CkEditor i was integrating CKFinder to the editor. I Used the Nuget to install the CKFinder. Everything was installed successfully, I followed the configuration found on https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/integration.html#integration_existing_application. Below is the code I added in the Startup.cs as mentioned by the tutorial. However, when I try to run the application I get the following error.

Type CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Commands.JsonParamtersBase`1[T] is a generic type definition

at the line

```
var connector = connectorBuilder.Build(connectorFactory);

private static void SetupConnector(IAppBuilder app)
    {
       
        var connectorFactory = new OwinConnectorFactory();
        var connectorBuilder = new ConnectorBuilder();
      


        connectorBuilder               
            .LoadConfig()
            .SetRequestConfiguration(
                (request, config) =>
                {
                    config.LoadConfig();

                   
                    config.AddBackend("default", new LocalStorage(@"~/Upload/"));
                    config.AddResourceType("images", builder => builder.SetBackend("default", "images"));
                    config.AddAclRule(new AclRule(
                        new StringMatcher("*"),
                        new StringMatcher("*"),
                        new StringMatcher("*"),
                        new Dictionary<Permission, PermissionType> { { Permission.All, PermissionType.Allow } }));
                    
                    var defaultBackend = config.GetBackend("default");
                    var keyValueStoreProvider = new FileSystemKeyValueStoreProvider(defaultBackend);
                    config.SetKeyValueStoreProvider(keyValueStoreProvider);
                }
            );

       
        var connector = connectorBuilder.Build(connectorFactory);           
        app.UseConnector(connector);
    }
```

[Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ1Oi.png)

If I disabled the Owin and I tried to run the application the CKEditor gives me an error and cannot find the connector's path.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue or how to resolve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The http connection is not completing or returning an error. So one possibility is the URL is wrong or the file doesn't exist or you are using the wrong TLS version. You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to check the URL.  First check sniffer and see if a request is being send.  If you do not see the request than check if TLS is shown. The request will only be sent after TLS authentication is completed.  TLS is required for HTTPS (secure).  If you are not seeing TLS then the error is in the configuration file (like filename wrong).  If a request is sent then check status in response.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng for your reply. I Used fiddler and there seems nothing wrong the Http request completes normally before it is redirected to the error. I suspect the file might be missing. During debugging the Connector Builder is getting 23 built in ckfinder commands i am not sure if there should be more or not.

Comment: Did you check the body of the response to see if there was any data?  What is the status of the response.  Is it 200 OK or an error number like 400/500.

Comment: It is 500 internal server error.

Comment: Check headers in the request.  One must be wrong or the parameter in the URL which is after the question mark in the URL.

Comment: The following is the headers i received

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcV29ya1xBUkFQXE1pZGRsZUJlYXRzLldlYi5VSVxNaWRkbGVCZWF0cy5XZWIuVUk=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 27 Oct 2020 14:03:21 GMT
Content-Length: 10999

Comment: The 500 status is in the response not the request.  It is interesting you are getting an Error response with a length of 10999.  Normal errors do not have data.  You should check the body of the response to see if there is additional debug info.

Comment: Apologies request headers:

Host: localhost:44304
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ar-QA;q=0.8,ar;q=0.7

Comment: Does not the Content length refers to the returned error page including the stack trace?

Comment: The error may be due to the 'Accept' in the header.  Looks like you are expecting JSON and getting an exception in the JSON deserialize.  With sniffer check the body in the response.   As I said earlier it is unusual to get a body with 10,999 bytes and a 500 error.  The server may not like the Accept and then giving a default response which may not be the JSON you are expecting.

Comment: Is the stack trace coming from the client or server?

Comment: Hello jdweng sorry for the late reply, I have no idea what is the issue might be issue with configuration with another package. i Added my custom uploader for the ckeditor and it is working now. Thank you for your help!